# getting offset in file from  RVA

Tags: 64-bit, portable-executable

I'm trying to read a PE file.
The problems is that the data uses RVA pointers while I need offset within the file
 to get what I need.
How can I convert the RVA to offset in the file?

Comment: Suppose you couldn't read it from the file, how does the PE loader work?

Comment: I don't know... Does it show the unwind info? and if I can read it from the file, what is the address offset from?

Comment: According to my information, they're relative to ImageBase (in the header)

Comment: the problem is that the value of "ImageBase" in the header is way bigger than the size of the executable.

Comment: Well yes, the position you get out of that is the position it would have in memory, not in the file.

Comment: so I DO need to load the module?

Comment: OK wait.. is the actual question: "how do I convert an RVA to an offset in the file" ?

Comment: hmmm... well I guess this is what I'm trying to do :)

Comment: Does this help? http://www.art0.org/reversing/portable-executable-converting-rva-to-file-offset-and-back

Comment: I think it will. If you post this as an answer, i'll accept it. I'll also update my question :)

Comment: Have you taken a look at [Matt Pietrek's PeDump sample](http://www.wheaty.net/downloads.htm)? He shows how that works.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To determine the file offset by RVA, you need:

1. to determine in which section points RVA.
2. subtract from your address relative virtual address of section
3. add to result the file offset of section

You will receive a file offset that you need.

Comment: <Weeps in joy> Hours! Hours! I've been struggling with this... Thank you for saying it clearly! <More weeping>

Answer (score 3):

Below example gives file offset of address of entry point from RVA. One can pass any pointer to get its disk offset from RVA.

**Basically we need to find in which section the address belongs. Once the correct section is identified use below formula to get offset.**

> DWORD retAddr = ptr - (sectionHeader->VirtualAddress) +
>        (sectionHeader->PointerToRawData);

then add file base address to get physical address

> retAddr+(PBYTE)lpFileBase

```
    LPCSTR fileName="exe_file_to_parse";
    HANDLE hFile; 
    HANDLE hFileMapping;
    LPVOID lpFileBase;
    PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER dosHeader;
    PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS peHeader;
    PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER sectionHeader;

    hFile = CreateFileA(fileName,GENERIC_READ,FILE_SHARE_READ,NULL,OPEN_EXISTING,FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,0);

    if(hFile==INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        printf("\n CreateFile failed in read mode \n");
        return 1;
    }

    hFileMapping = CreateFileMapping(hFile,NULL,PAGE_READONLY,0,0,NULL);

    if(hFileMapping==0)
    {
        printf("\n CreateFileMapping failed \n");
        CloseHandle(hFile);
        return 1;
    }

    lpFileBase = MapViewOfFile(hFileMapping,FILE_MAP_READ,0,0,0); // Base pointer to file

    if(lpFileBase==0)
    {
        printf("\n MapViewOfFile failed \n");
        CloseHandle(hFileMapping);
        CloseHandle(hFile);
        return 1;
    }

    dosHeader = (PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER) lpFileBase;  //pointer to dos headers

    if(dosHeader->e_magic==IMAGE_DOS_SIGNATURE)
    {
        //if it is executable file print different fileds of structure
        //dosHeader->e_lfanew : RVA for PE Header
        printf("\n DOS Signature (MZ) Matched");

        //pointer to PE/NT header
        peHeader = (PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS) ((u_char*)dosHeader+dosHeader->e_lfanew);

        if(peHeader->Signature==IMAGE_NT_SIGNATURE)
        {
            printf("\n PE Signature (PE) Matched \n");
            // valid executable so we can proceed

            //address of entry point
            DWORD ptr = peHeader->OptionalHeader.AddressOfEntryPoint;

            //instead of AEP send any pointer to get actual disk offset of it
            printf("\n RVA : %x \n",ptr); // this is in memory address i.e. RVA
            //suppose any one wants to know actual disk offset of "address of entry point" (AEP)

            sectionHeader = IMAGE_FIRST_SECTION(peHeader); //first section address
            UINT nSectionCount = peHeader->FileHeader.NumberOfSections;
            UINT i=0;
            //check in which section the address belongs
            for( i=0; i<=nSectionCount; ++i, ++sectionHeader )
            {
                if((sectionHeader->VirtualAddress) > ptr)
                {
                    sectionHeader--;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if(i>nSectionCount)
            {
                sectionHeader = IMAGE_FIRST_SECTION(peHeader);
                UINT nSectionCount = peHeader->FileHeader.NumberOfSections;
                for(i=0; i<nSectionCount-1; ++i,++sectionHeader);
            }

            //once the correct section is found below formula gives the actual disk offset 
            DWORD retAddr = ptr - (sectionHeader->VirtualAddress) +
                    (sectionHeader->PointerToRawData);
            printf("\n Disk Offset : %x \n",retAddr+(PBYTE)lpFileBase);
            // retAddr+(PBYTE)lpFileBase contains the actual disk offset of address of entry point

        }
        UnmapViewOfFile(lpFileBase);
        CloseHandle(hFileMapping);
        CloseHandle(hFile);
        //getchar();
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\n DOS Signature (MZ) Not Matched \n");
        UnmapViewOfFile(lpFileBase);
        CloseHandle(hFileMapping);
        CloseHandle(hFile);
        return 1;
    }
```

Comment: added some description as well as comments.

Comment: Can you please explain why are we adding file base pointer `lpFileBase` to Raw Disk Offset? Looks like we are adding raw offsets to virtual offset which is not right, I think.


I thought that `lpFileBase` is Virtual Address where file was mapped.
To get Virtual Address of Entry Point of this file we need to add RVA of Entry Point to `lpFileBase`, then we will get VA of Entry Point of this mapped file.

Comment: I think I missed that files are mapped to memory as 1 to 1 from their hard disk image. Correct me if I'm wrong. So to get `Entry Point` of memory mapped file we need to use `Raw Offsets` from `file base pointer` in memory. Therefore, first, we get `Entry Point Raw Offset` from its `RVA`, second, add `file base pointer` (VA in memory) to this `Raw Offset` to get `VA of EntryPoint of memory mapped file`.

Answer (score 2):

```
file Offset = RVAOfData - Virtual Offset + Raw Offset
```

Example:
Our resource section (".rsrc") details:
Virtual offset: F000
Raw offset: C600

[image]

Lets look on one of the resource we have:
Name: BIN
RVA of Data: F0B0
File offset: ?

[image]

```
fileOffset = RVAOfData - Virtual Offset + Raw Offset   
=>  C6B0   = F0B0      - F000           + C600
```

**File offset: C6B0**

[image]

Reference:
[Understanding RVAs and Import Tables - by Sunshine](http://www.sunshine2k.de/reversing/tuts/tut_rvait.htm)

Function in C#:

```
// Example:
//   RVA: F0B0
//   Virtual offset: F000 ("RVA" in PEview)
//   Raw offset: C600 ("Pointer to Raw Data" in PEview)
//   fileOffset = F0B0 - F000 + C600 = C6B0
private static uint rvaToFileOffset(uint i_Rva, uint i_VirtualOffset, uint i_RawOffset)
{
    return (i_Rva - i_VirtualOffset + i_RawOffset);
}
```